# Display a sum of value in json in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this json and I would like to view a sum of available_funds in my Component in React.js. If is this possible? could I ask for an example of viewing this? Because I can not do it.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    id_owner: 1,
    account_bill: 123456789,
    available_funds: 100
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    id_owner: 1,
    account_bill: 111111111,
    available_funds: 20
  }
]
```

React.js component:

```
class AvailableFunds extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      availableFunds: '',
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/bills/1')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          availableFunds: data.available_funds,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {});
  }
```

...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your data is an array of objects, you can use reduce to get the sum:

```
data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.available_funds, 0)
```

Comment: Can u write a example full code of display this value in my component?

Comment: @ReactRouter2 You just need to replace `data.available_funds` in your `setState` function with the code @khartnett has provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/api/bills/1')
        .then(({ data }) => {
        var sum = 0;
        if(typeof data == 'object'){
            data.forEach(funds => {
                sum += parseFloat(funds.available_funds);
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            availableFunds: sum,
            isLoading: false
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {});
}
```